# Sending context from one page to Another page in Aurelia

Tags: c#, .net, aurelia

How to pass the context from one page to another page in Aurelia??? and need to keep the context value until the 2nd page works finish.

Comment: what does context mean here ? shared data ?

Comment: for example from customer page i am redirecting to Agreement page. so in that case customer information i want to keep in context and i need to access the information in agreement page(instead of passing from URL.) until the agreement page task in done.
ya its some kind of shared data i guess.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` for this need, so long as you're not trying to persist sensitive data.  If that's the case, then you should be looking at managing the information on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

If users will always be on the customer page before moving to the agreement page, you can simply create a singleton class to store the shared data and inject it into the customer page and agreement page view-models.

Comment: but in that case if the url refresh in agreement page. that shared data is clearing :(